# Combinate JSTL var with Java method

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How can I use the Jstl attribute ${theDetail.id} from a Jstl foreach inside a java function? I have tried a lot, but nothing works.

```
<c:forEach items="<%= facade.getAllDetails() %>" var="theDetail">

    // how to use ${theDetail.id} inside this java function
    <c:forEach items="<%= facade.getSomeStuffById(...) %>" vars="theStuff"> 
        ${theStuf.name} 
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use scriptlet expressions inside JSP tags. In fact, never use scriptlets at all. The JSP tags are designed to use the JSP EL expressions. Not scriptlet expressions.

The way to write your code is, assuming `facade` is an attribute of some scope

```
<c:forEach items="${facade.allDetails}" var="theDetail">

    <c:forEach items="${facade.getSomeStuffById('someHardCodedId')}" var="theStuff"> 
        ${theStuff.name} 
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yes, thats where i'm looking for. but how can I use it with the id of {theDetail.id}? When I try to add ${theDetail.id} inside getSomeStuffById() I get an 500 error.

Comment: `${facade.getSomeStuffById(theDetail.id)}`